# HighCharts: Bar columns don't reach x-Axis on drill up

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am struggling with a HighChart/HighStock problem. I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e3xqv7e/45/) to explain my problem! When the user uses a drill down on one of the bar colums, the y-axis may shrink which causes the x-axis to get higher. This is no problem, but when the user goes back to the overview through  a drill up, the previous x-axis length is implemented for the bar columns, while the x-axis gets lower. I can't find anything in the documentation to help my problem and I haven't found a similar problem.

The drilldown which I am using:

```
drilldown: {
    drillUpButton: {
        relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
        position: {
            y: 0,
            x: 0
        },
        theme: {
            fill: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: 'silver',
            r: 0,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    fill: '#D2D2D2'
                },
                select: {
                    stroke: '#039',
                    fill: '#D2D2D2'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{"data":......}]
}
```

Could someone please help me adjust the code so that on the drill-up event the bar columns are re-configured to reach the x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug with drilldown animation which appears only when a navigator is enabled. Reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6176).

Should work without the animation:

```
     drilldown: {
                animation: false,
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/3e3xqv7e/47/

In general, I think a navigator was not meant to work with drilldowns, so making it work correctly might be tricky. An option [series.showInLegend](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.showInNavigator) works, though, except the min/max of the navigator are changed after drillup - so you need to set it properly.

```
 drillup: function (e) {
      this.navigator.xAxis.setExtremes(0, 4, true, false);
   /*   this.navigator.xAxis.update({
        min: 0,
        max: 4
      }, true);*/
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/c1nqpz7d/2/